# Fancybox appearing at bottom of page when site is in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, fancybox

I built a static site initially and am now in the process of converting it to a wordpress site.  You can find it [here](http://training.mercury.stellarbluewebdesign.com/LittlestTumorFoundation/) The last image in the right column, when clicked, should open up a fancybox and play a video.  It worked very well in the static site, but for some reason in wordpress the box appears at the bottom of the page instead of the center.  I'm pretty sure it is seeing the css because I can click on the link and find it.

Comment: If you're referring to the video, it appears to be working in Chrome, what browser are you working with?

Comment: It works, but it appears at the bottom of the page instead of the center(both vertically and horizontally) I have firefox, chrome, and IE and it doesn't work in any of them for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the result of the validation of your page

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://training.mercury.stellarbluewebdesign.com/LittlestTumorFoundation/

**Notice** the comment :

```
Byte-Order Mark found in UTF-8 File.
The Unicode Byte-Order Mark (BOM) in UTF-8 encoded files
is known to cause problems for some text editors and older
browsers.
```

Also notice

```
Line 1, Column 1: Non-space characters found without seeing a 
doctype first. Expected <!DOCTYPE html>
```

Passing your code through an editor in `ansi` mode (and showing all symbols), this is what I get :

[image]

Those preceding hidden characters before the `DOCTYPE` in your document makes your browser run in quirks mode hence the unexpected behavior of fancybox (which needs the document in standards mode to run properly)

What you have to do is to save your WP (php) files in an editor using `UTF-8 without BOM` encoding and upload them again (and alternatively forcing your ftp software to upload in binary mode)

Comment: HOLY JESUS how on earth did you figure that out.  In a bajillion years I never would have thought to look at that.

Comment: @user1815207 : first thing you should do with troublesome sites is validate ;)